# kafka.common.OffsetOutOfRangeException - for no valid reason

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I am using `kafka-node` library to consume the kafka messages from node.js. This is the simple code I tried to consume:

```
    consumer = new Consumer(
    client,
    [
        { topic: 't', partition: 0 }, { topic: 't1', partition: 1 }
    ],
    {
        autoCommit: false
    }
   );

consumer.on('message', function (message) {
    console.log(message);
});
```

This was working perfectly sometime before, but now I keep on getting this error:

> kafka.common.OffsetOutOfRangeException: Request for offset 19 but we only have log segments in the range 0 to 0.

I don't understand what makes Kafka to throw this error without any reason for the same code which was working before, I haven't given offset as 19 no where. I tried deleting the topics, logs etc. I keep on getting this error. Can anyone please guide me how to handle this?

Comment: try to use the kafka-console consumer script to see if the topic has any data at all .. from your kafka home run `bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper xx.xx.xx.xx:2181 --topic your_topic --from-beginning` .. also check what is the retention hour set in your config file .. if by any chance it is over the topic will no longer hold any records

Comment: Yes it log retention period was set to 168, I changed it to 1 now. Again facing same error and yes if I run that command I am getting data. @user2720864

Comment: I haven't work with node.js and kafka .. is there any option/flag which will force it to read from the beginning of the topic ?

Comment: Yes there maybe something like that, I'm trying to look for the same, as I'm new here not much aware of that :)

Comment: one more thing you can do is to check inside kafka topic log folder .  see if log file exists with that specific offset in it.